# BootStrap move submit button after input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm newbie in bootstrap and i'm using this website `http://getbootstrap.com/` now i want to move submit button after input tag.

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

in this sample after change `navbar-form navbar-left` to `navbar-form navbar-right` that using `float: left|right` but my language is RTL and this is for LRT language. how to move it with bootstrap class's

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to float with classes?
If that is the case, then you can use

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Submit</button>
```